# I can not remove nodejs package from linux AWS

Tags: linux

I am trying to upgrade my cuurent nodejs package, I first have to remove it, howvere, I am unable to do it

```
[root@*** simple-react-panel]# yum info nodejs
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Available Packages
Name        : nodejs
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 2
Version     : 10.19.0
Release     : 1nodesource
Size        : 20 M
Repo        : nodesource/x86_64
Summary     : JavaScript runtime
URL         : http://nodejs.org
License     : MIT and ASL 2.0 and ISC and BSD
Description : Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime
            : for easily building fast, scalable network applications.
            : Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that
            : makes it lightweight and efficient, perfect for data-intensive
            : real-time applications that run across distributed devices.

[root@*** simple-react-panel]# yum remove nodejs
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No Match for argument: nodejs
No Packages marked for removal
[root@ip-192-168-5-243 simple-react-panel]#
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my commands?

Answer (score 0):

Along with remove node ,you might neet to remove the local yum node repo. Please try this one.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum
sudo yum remove -y nodejs
sudo rm /etc/yum.repos.d/nodesource*
sudo yum clean all
```